# turning morse into english from a txt file in C, only iterates 1 char in the string before stopping

Tags: c, string

Using the code below it only reads one char and does not convert morse to letter. My idea was to create a string of one morse "letter" and put it in the convert function, however only 1 char is being read since I am only seeing a single 1 printed on the screen after the string itself is printed. The string only consists of '-' , '.' , ' '. I was wondering if anyone knows what the solution might be.

```
char convertToLetter(M* data, char word[10]) {

int size = 0;
char correct;
while (size < 60)
{
    int compare = strcmp(word, data->morse);
    if (compare == 0) {
        correct = data->letter;
    }
    data++;
    size++;
}
correct = '\0';
return correct;
}

int main(){

//some code here for opening a file.

char curSent[200];
char letter[6] = "";
int i = 0;
char* fullString = (char*)malloc(1000 * sizeof(char));
fullString[0] = '\0';
while (fgets(curSent, 200, inFile) != NULL) {
    
    if (curSent[0] != '\n') {
        
        curSent[strlen(curSent) - 1] = '\0';
        strcat_s(fullString,1000, curSent);
        
    }
    else {
        printf("%s", fullString);
        printf("\n\n");
        
        int j = 0;
        while (i < strlen(fullString)) {
            if (fullString[i] != ' ') {
                fullString[i] = letter[j];
                i++;
                j++;
                printf("%d \n", 1);
                
            }else if (fullString[i + 1] == ' ' && fullString[i] == ' ') {

                printf("%d", 2);
                printf(" %c", convertToLetter(dictionary, letter));
                memset(letter, 0, strlen(letter));
                j = 0;
                i = i + 2;
                    
            }else if (fullString[i] == ' ') {
                printf("%d", 3);
                printf("%c", convertToLetter(dictionary, letter));
                memset(letter, 0, strlen(letter));
                j = 0;
                i = i++;
            }
                
            
        }
        
        memset(fullString, 0, strlen(fullString));
        i = 0;
        
    }

    
}
//printf("%s", fullString);
getchar();
return 0;

}
```

Comment: The code has multitude of problems. Slow down, take a deep breath, write a *much smaller* program. I suggest one that converts a single letter. Make it work, then extend it to convert a single word, then a line.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.